# Install PHP-CGI with LAMP Tasksel

Tags: php, ubuntu, lamp

I installed PHP APACHE AND MYSQL using the LAMP Package

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

There is now a requirement for php-cgi. How do I install this as well ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cgi
```